# how to find the exact data value on click event or mouse hover in a time series graph drawn by datashader and holoview

Tags: python, bigdata, holoviews, datashader

[image]

Here I am trying to visualize 1bn data.
The below scatter plot represents graph of time value pair.
eg:

df:

```
TIME,VAL
145000000, 1.464000, 
150000000, 1.466000, 
155000000, 1.461250, 
160000000, 1.481750, 
165000000, 1.493500, 
170000000, 1.514500, 
175000000, 1.524000, 
180000000, 1.543750, 
185000000, 1.553750, 
190000000, 1.582000, 
195000000, 1.594000, 
200000000, 1.625000, 
205000000, 1.639500, 
210000000, 1.679250, 
215000000, 1.697250, 
220000000, 1.720000,
```

I need to find the exact time value pair that is being mapped to `(x, y)` point.
Is there any way to find the real time value of particular `(x, y)` click on raster image being rendered on screen

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to find the individual row contributing to a specific point, the answer is that you can't.

Unlike matplotlib, datashader is not rendering individual points. Instead, it first defines the image boundaries, then using the requested number of pixels, computes the range of values in `(x, y)` which fall into each pixel. It then bins/discretizes your data, so the rendering engine is only working with summary statistics for each pixel - not the individual values from your source data. This is what makes datashader so powerful when rendering huge datasets, but it also means that nowhere is there a mapping from rows to pixels.

You could of course identify the boundaries of a given pixel and then filter your dataset to pull all rows with data falling into these bounds. But there's no guarantee that the match will be unique (this depends on your data).

Comment: "You could of course identify the boundaries of a given pixel and then filter your dataset to pull all rows with data falling into these bounds", It will be helpful if you can give some example/reference how to achieve this? I could not able to find the inverse mapping from pixel to real rows which contributes to a particular pixel.

Comment: it would be helpful for us if you provided your code which you use to set up the data and create the plot as a [mre]. otherwise we have to make up our own example, which is a decent amount of work :)

Comment: Thanks @Michael for acknowledging. Please find the below example I have saved in codepen.io., in css tab I mentioned the data which has to be saved as a csv file in local. And in JS tab I have mentioned the code for same, I have mentioned a small amount of data around 500 rows. tough there is more than 11.5Million rows.  
                                                       
https://codepen.io/debashishsamantaray/pen/eYjBjpP

Comment: you're more likely to get help if you put together a code-generated example rather than uploading multiple data files. in any case, please modify your question to include the relevant detail rather than posting in comments. see this post for more context: [crafting minimal bug reports](https://matthewrocklin.com/minimal-bug-reports)

Answer (score 1):

Michael Delgado is correct that the rendered image doesn't contain information about the rows, but (a) you can use the HoloViews "inspect" tools to look up the original datapoints mapped into that pixel (automating the process he describes; see https://examples.pyviz.org/ship_traffic), and (b) it's on our list to provide such an inverse mapping from pixel to rows, with the constraint that only `n` datapoints can be returned for each pixel (see proposal in https://github.com/holoviz/datashader/issues/1126). Once we have such a mapping, it should be trivial to provide hover and click information in holoviews for datashader plots without the cost of searching through the original dataset. Wish us luck, and in the meantime, use `inspect_points`!

Comment: This is really cool! Thanks for the extra info and roadmap! And for the great work on datashader - I’m such a fan :)